# Jetty Server behavior when ThreadPool can't accept new requests

Tags: java, jetty

I've configured my Jetty server with a bounded ThreadPool and a bounded QueueSize. What would be the behavior when this is actually hit? Ie, a user submits a HTTP request to the server, and Jetty is unable to get a thread/queue-slot to fulfill the request.

I would have expected the server to respond to the client with a 500 error of some form. But from my local testing, it appears that the client doesn't get any response at all.

What does Jetty do in this case? Is there any way for me to configure Jetty to send a 500 response to the user when this occurs?